# Regex won't allow space in beginning of word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

can any one know how to don't let input in the first character space? Trying to do it on .net with regex and still can't find solution.
Example (pretend that _ is space now):

- `_Word` - bad
- `Word` - good
- `Word word` - good
- `_word word` - bad
- `__word` - bad

Answer (score 3):

`^\s` matches any string that starts with whitespace. If you want to invalidate a string.

If you want to positively match valid strings, you could look for a string that starts with non-whitespace: `^\S`

Depending on what you're trying to do, it might be preferable to trim the string which will allow you to simply tolerate such a minor flaw in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Something like so: `^[^\s]` will yield `true` for any string which does not start with a white space character(s). Explanation (just in case):

- `^`: Match the start of the string.
- `[^\s]`: Any character which is not a white space. `[\S]` is another way of writing `[^\s]`.

Comment: For a "starts with" condition, it is of no interest what follows after the first character. Either the string starts with whitespace from character one or it doesn't. The `+` is superfluous here.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: It's a on habit I guess, but you're right. Change applied.

Answer (score 0):

So you dont want a space at the start of the string..

You can do this

```
^[^\s].*
```

`\s` is used to determine space.

`[^\s]` says match any character except space

`.*` says match any character till end

**OR**

Simply use StartsWith method

```
if(yourString.StartsWith(" ")==true)
{
//bad
}
else
{
//good
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need regx here.

You can check the white space as below.

```
if(" Word - "[0] == ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another non-Regex solution

```
bool startsWithNonSpaceCharacter = !yourString.StartsWith(" ");
```